# Obtain the command line from a running process from the Command Prompt

Tags: cmd, parameters, command

I wanted to determine the command-line arguments of a running process at the Command Prompt (`cmd.exe`).

E.g., if I started my `abc.exe` program as follows:

```
abc -d
```

I want to determine the whole command line later. The `TASKLIST` utility does not provide this info, because it just reports the exe name and not the arguments with which the process was started.

Comment: Related ServerFault.com question: https://serverfault.com/q/696460/176094

Comment: @mklement0 Think this topic delivers a helpful answer and I would search for it right here, rather than on server...whatever

Comment: @SamGinrich, I agree: I wasn't the one who closed it, I just edited it (in fact, I had up-voted it). You can nominate it for reopening, as I just have (not sure how many votes it needs)

Comment: `wmic process where "CommandLine like '%%abc.exe%%' get processid,commandline`

Answer (score 10):

Here is a GUI-based method (Tested on Windows 7 - YMMV).  I don't know of an easy method to get this data from the command-line.

1. Open the Task Manager (CTRL+SHIFT+ESC), and go to the Processes tab.
2. From the View menu -> Select Columns...
3. Scroll to the very bottom and select "Command Line"
4. In the newly-shown "Command Line" column, you can see the entire command that started the process, including any command-line parameters

Command-line method:

1. Start a PowerShell with administrator priviledges
2. Use the Get-WmiObject to list processes and filter the process name above. Add/remove fields through the select statement below - example:

   ```
   Get-WmiObject win32_process -Filter "name like '%notepad.exe'"|select CreationDate,ProcessId,CommandLine|ft -AutoSize
   ```

Note: The process name "notepad.exe" is used for this example, substitute the name for your specific scenario.

Comment: Actually, i wanted to know how to do this from DOS CommadLine .

Comment: I have figured out a method . I used Tasklist to obtain the processID s of each process and then using wmic obtained the actual commandLine .

Comment: wmic process where processID=12345 get commandLine will give the actual command using which the process was started along with its command Line arguments .

Answer (score -2):

the method from mellanmokb works acutally, but i think the question whould be? can i see in in code maybe, if that is the case, are you using C# o VB?.

If the case is C# you can see it in [msdn library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96s74eb0%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

There you can see that the arguments arrives at the Main(string[] args), and this is a string that you can read as argument = args[i] with i the number of the argument you want

for example if you call args[2] on the commandline was text.exe test here there

args[2] will be here.

remmember that args[i] is a string always.

hope this helped

Comment: But it is not for application you are writing.

Comment: Hi Manoj , Thanx for the help .. But what i actually wanted is to know from commandLine in DOS if there is any way .. Actually i have figured out a method using wmic and Tasklist .