# Why would one do this when storing a secure string?

Tags: powershell, credentials

Would this in some way make it more secure than just a secure string and storing it in a credential?  Why would someone do this?

```
$secVal = read-host  -AsSecureString -prompt "Enter xstoreuser password"
$strVal = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($secVal)
$dasPassword = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($strVal)
```

and then later

```
psftp -l somelogin -pw $dasPassword -P 22 -b .\ftp.txt somehost
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The technique you're showing is *not* about making the command *more* secure - *on the contrary***:

You need to do extra work to recover the plain-text password from the `[securestring]` instance, because **in order to pass a password to an *external program*** such as `psftp.exe` **you need an *insecure* *plain-text* representation, because external programs know nothing about .NET secure strings**.

[How secure is SecureString?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.securestring#how-secure-is-securestring) tells you about .NET secure strings and their limitations in general.

---

As an aside: The command for extracting the plain-text password can be simplified a little via an aux. `[pscredential]` instance:

```
# Returns the plain-text content of secure string $secVal:
(New-Object pscredential somelogin, $secVal).GetNetworkCredential().Password
```

---

The **only secure approach** is to **avoid plain-text passwords altogether** and **use a [PKI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_key_infrastructure) approach** (based on public and private keys) instead, if supported by the target program.

---

To **demonstrate** that the **plain-text approach is *insecure*** (even without the use of an intermediate variable to store the unencrypted password):

```
# Create a [pscredential] instance with a secure-string password:
# Note: To make this demo self-contained, I'm converting *from* plain
#       text in order to construct the credential object.
#       Note that you should never do that in production code.
#       The need to specify -Force to do it is a reminder that it
#       normally shouldn't be done.
$cred = New-Object pscredential someuser,
          (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force 'actualPassword')

# Open a new hidden window that passes the password *as plain text* to 
# `cmd /c echo` (and then waits for a keypress, to keep the process alive).
$ps = Start-Process -PassThru -WindowStyle Hidden cmd "/c echo $($cred.GetNetworkCredential().Password) & pause"

# Now inspect the process' command line using CIM (WMI):
(Get-CimInstance Win32_Process -Filter "ProcessID = $($ps.ID)").CommandLine

# Kill (stop) the sample process.
$ps | Stop-Process
```

The above yields `"C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe" /c echo actualPassword & pause`, demonstrating that the plain-text password can indeed be obtained by other processes.

You can also use ***GUI methods* for inspecting a running process' command line**: Task Manager (`Taskmgr.exe`) or, without potential truncation, [SysInternals' Process Explorer (`procexp.exe`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer), which, however, must be installed on demand - see [this ServerFault answer](https://serverfault.com/a/696532/176094).

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7494073/commandline-arguments-of-running-process-in-dos