# How to pass command line arguments to putty without making them visible in powershell / cmd?

Tags: powershell, process, putty, cmd, plink

When a process runs in Windows, if you pass command line arguments to it, they are visible if the process is running, making the passing of plain-text sensitive data using this method a really bad idea.

How does one prevent this from happening, short of implementing a public / private key infrastructure?

Do you just run everything via `plink`, since it exits right away after running the command (of course you have to make sure that it actually does exit)

See related questions below to refer to what I'm talking about:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7494073/commandline-arguments-of-running-process-in-dos
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53808314/why-would-one-do-this-when-storing-a-secure-string/53808379?noredirect=1#comment94523315_53808379

Comment: you can use a wrapper bat file w/@echo off to hide it

Comment: @dandavis It's being called from powershell (or it could be) I don't want to write things out to a file that's a bad idea.

Comment: if it's not in a file or environ or argument, then it gets more complicated, something like redis.

Comment: Oh so like pull something from the network?  Wouldn't you have to authenticate against that first?

Comment: And I just do that echo off in cmd?

Comment: could be localhost, and _might_ need auth, depending on usage. i think `echo off` is just for BAT files iirc.

Comment: the problem is worse than you think.  regardless of being able to see what's passed while it's running, if the Windows machine is running a tool like Sysmon (and they should), then the execution parameters are stored in the event log in perpetuity.  your safest bet is not pass sensitive information via the command-line (assuming passwords).  the fix is to run the script with the credentials they require to perform the seemingly elevated operation.

Comment: Ahh... I missed putty in the title which also clears up why you specified plink.  if you pass passwords via plink, they'll be visible in memory and potentially in event logs.  certificates are the only way i'm aware of to get around this problem

Comment: @thepip3r What kind of certificates are you talking about?  SSL? Signed powershell scripts?  Do you mean public / private keys (not really a certificate as far as I know)

Comment: OPs, why was this migrated?

Comment: @leeand00 Probably migrated because this is more about executing it in such a way so that the password isn't clearly visible, rather than completely removed from the system.

Comment: yes... meant key pair, not cert.